# How to apply SVG and font filters to amcharts4?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to apply filters to my JS object, where `<%=strKey%>` is a dynamically scripted object name, so, each iteration, the name changes.

```
        // dynamically writing JS - key value is the chart name
        var <%=strKey%> = am4core.create("<%=strKey%>", am4charts.GaugeChart);      // has to mach the HTML IDs
        <%=strKey%>.innerRadius = am4core.percent(82);    // innerRadius begins at 82%, leaving white-space inside the gauge
```

The [documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/) lists JSON format only.  How would I apply this to my implementation?

I'm actually trying to get a shadow to appear under the semi-circular gauge.  Suggestions please?

Comment: You are referencing the docs for v3 and are using amcharts4

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [DropShadowFilter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dropshadowfilter/) to add a shadow to your chart:

```
chart.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

You can use `blur`, `dx` and `dy` to customize the shadow:

```
var shadow = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
shadow.blur = 3.5;
shadow.dx = 5;
shadow.dy = 7;
chart.filters.push(shadow);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBjReJ) is a code pen showing that shadow. To create a custom SVG filter you can follow [this official tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-custom-filters/).

Comment: Great, but it applies the filter to everything.  What if I just want it on the chart and not the label?

Comment: You can just use `axis.renderer.filters` to add the filter there. I also update the code pen.