# How to change font colors and lower vertical align labels with gauge charts in amcharts4?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to add two lines to the label of an amcharts4 gauge chart with a different font per line:

[image]

Even though I have `horizontalCenter` set to `middle`, font is still left-aligned.

```
        // label
        var label = <%=strKey%>.radarContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
        label.isMeasured = false;
        label.fontSize = 22;
        label.x = am4core.percent('<%=ThisChart.Average%>');      // label inside
        label.y = am4core.percent(100);
        label.fontFamily = "Arial";
        label.fontColr = "#ff0000";
        label.fontWeight = "900";  // "normal" | "bold" | "bolder" | "lighter" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900"
        label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
        label.text = "<%=FormatNumber(ThisChart.Average,,0)%>%\n<%=ThisChart.ChartTitle%>";
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Secondly, it appears I'm limited to the bottom of the chart.  I can add an additional label outside of the chart ("Progress"), but wondering if I can do this as part of the label.  The documentation doesn't seem to show how to set multiple labels, nor how to change the color of this label.

===================

## Update

Since I have two axis and one label, I want to use the label text for each axis, since the font sizing and colors differ for each, rather than using the singular chart label.

In trying to follow [this](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3446cd09288ee4e5901c73b3970adbfe?editors=0010) example, I'm getting this:

[image]

Using this code, where `<%=strKey%>` is a dynamic object name:

```
        // axis settings
        var axis0 = <%=strKey%>.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        axis0.min = 0;
        axis0.max = 100;  // average
        axis0.strictMinMax = true;
        axis0.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;  // false forouter label ticks
        axis0.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
        axis0.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
        axis0.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
        //axis0.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#f00");
        //axis0.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

        var labelTemplate = axis0.renderer.labels.template;
        labelTemplate.rotation = 0;
        labelTemplate.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        labelTemplate.verticalCenter = "bottom";
        labelTemplate.dy = 10; // moves it a bit down;
        labelTemplate.inside = false; // this is done to avoid settings which are not suitable when label is rotated
        labelTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#f00");
        labelTemplate.background.fill = am4core.color("#ccc");
```

I think I may have to reference `radarContainer` for this, and only want one label positioned per axis.

**Update**

This is obviously not what I'm looking for as I need two lines with different fonts for the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [label.textAlign](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#textAlign_property) to set the alignment to center and [label.fill](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#fill_property) to set the text color:

```
label.textAlign = "middle";
label.fill = am4core.color('red');
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBjgXB) is a code pen showing the result.

Alternatively you can use two labels to also use different colors and font sizes. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEzgqm) is another code pen showing that behaviour.

To position your label you can use the following properties:

- [label.x](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#x_property)
- [label.y](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#y_property)
- [label.verticalCenter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#verticalCenter_property)
- [label.horizontalCenter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#horizontalCenter_property)

Comment: Can I create one label for each axis, rather than showing ticks?  See my update.

Comment: I'm thinking using the axis template is not what I'm looking for.  So, how can I create a label template with varying fonts and colors?

Comment: You can also move a label to the top with `label.y = 0` and adding it directly to the `chart`, not `chart.radarContainer`.

Comment: You can use multiple labels, like I showed in my second example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEzgqm).

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I found a way to use the axis option but your option is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: One last thing.  I can't seem to get the applied shadow away from the label. No shadow on label please?

Comment: Look at my last comment on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197576/9662601) to your shadow question.

Comment: Problem is, using `label.background.filters.clear();` keeps a white box around the text and shadows that.  Your example uses the axis text, not the label text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190157/discussion-between-samuel-philipp-and-elhaix).